# Find Data from selected Checkbox and Multiselect Jquery to Datatables by Join Filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I managed to create a filter with column filtering by selected value (single value), but i was stuck when i try to make it filter column and double values (by using checkbox). The question is, how can i join two or more values i've checked from the checkbox inside the spesific column i've declared?. Can anyone please help me to give the example or ide for fixing this trouble? Thankyou

This is my existing code

```
//Select Form
<select id="strFltr" class="form-control form-control-sm" multiple="multiple">
<option>STARTER</option>
<option>NON STARTER</option>

//Filter Column
$('#strFltr').on('change', function(){
                        oTable.column(3).search(this.value).draw();
                    });
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) you only able to pass there a string parameter, but you may treat it as a regexp. So, `$(this).val()` will be equal to array of strings, which can be joined with `|` (`or` regexp operator), and also you'd need to escape values for regexp:

```
var values = $(this).val().map(function (value) {
   return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(value);
})
var value = values.join('|');
oTable.column(3).search(value, true, false).draw();
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but in this example it will use partial match. If the join string is 'abc'|'cde' it will match 'abc' and 'abcde', how to solve this and have an exact match for every single value in the join string?

Comment: @andQlimax Could you give an example of the string you're need to test, like `abc cde` or `abccde` and not `abcde`? For separate words it is possible to wrap into `\b`

Comment: If you need an exact match, it can be done like this: `/^(abc|cde)$/`

Comment: where that should be applied? to the variable "value":   value = "/^(" + value + "$/"; it doesn't do an exact match, in my case the strings that get matched are "Development and Test" and "Development", instead I'm searching only for "Development" and "Execution" for example

Comment: Something like this should do: `'^(' + value + ')$'`, as the string should not include `/`, I assume, and you missed the `)` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get multi selected values by val().

For example,

```
$('#strFltr').val()
```

You can search multiple values by pipe(|) separator .

For example,

```
oTable.column(3).search("STARTER|NON STARTER").draw();
```

If your jQuery version support **join**, then you can do something like below,

```
var seachlist =  $('#strFltr').val().join("|");
oTable.column(3).search(seachlist, true, false).draw();
```

Comment: i dont know why but its working now.. but when i try to join search NON<space>STARTER with STARTER it's not joining search, but when i try to join STARTER with ACTIVE(another categories) it showed up, maybe you know why?

Comment: It should be work. Please post your code if issue are still there.

Comment: it works, but when i select value theres some (space) between like NON<space>STARTER it cant joining

`$('#stsFltr').on('change', function(){ var searchlist = $('#stsFltr').val().join("|"); oTable.column(3).search(searchlist, true).draw(); });`

Comment: Try to disable smart search like  oTable.column(3).search(seachlist, true, false).draw(); As i edited answer.

Comment: Yap, sure it works perfectly now, thank you very much for the answer and helping me :) sorry for my mistake

Comment: > `You can search multiple values by pipe(|) separator .`
You can't. You can with `true` as a second parameter only.

> `If your jQuery version support join`.
`val()` for multiple select returns plain Array and does nothing to jQuery.  `Array.prototype.join` supported by all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc).

Comment: great explain, thank you very much everyone :) thanks @extempl and Jitendra